# How to combine 2 list into pairs of nested list?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list

So, I have 2 lists:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2= [6,7,8,9,10]
```

The desired output:

```
newlist = [[1,6],[2,7],[3,8],[4,9],[5,10]]
```

How to do that in Python?

Comment: you can try : `[*map(list,zip(list1,list2))]` or `list(map(list,zip(list1,list2)))` , for an array use: `np.column_stack((list1,list2))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `zip`, but output is list of tuples, so added `map` by `list`:

```
a = list(map(list, zip(list1, list2)))
print (a)
[[1, 6], [2, 7], [3, 8], [4, 9], [5, 10]]
```

Or use list comprehension:

```
a = [list(x) for x in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the zip funciton

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2= [6,7,8,9,10]
list3 = list(zip(list1, list2))
print(list3)
```

Comment: output is list of tuples, not list of lists